# Событие change и добавленный элемент

Tags: jquery, javascript

джаваскпиптом на страницу при определённых условиях добавляются input  (с помошью .before()  )

так же в коде для этих инпутов указана функция на событие .change()

но дело в том, что интпуты появляются интерактивно и их изначально нет на странице, а когда они появляются фунция change к ним не привязывается и их не видит, что можно сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

разобрался

$( document ).on( events, selector, data, handler );  // jQuery 1.7+

на место events - поставил change

на место селектора - нужный класс

и далее функция